# R set default origin for as.Date

Tags: r, as.date

Is there a way to set default origin for as.Date?
I did this function to workaround:

```
as.date=function(x, origin='1970-01-01') as.Date(x, origin=origin)
```

For example:

```
as.Date(0)
Error in as.Date.numeric(0) : 'origin' deve ser especificado

as.date(0)
[1] "1970-01-01"
```

Answer (score 15):

The zoo package adds a default origin:

```
library(zoo)

as.Date(0)
## [1] "1970-01-01"
```

### Update

This is several years later but it looks like R has added `.Date` so we can now do this using only base R.

```
.Date(0)
## [1] "1970-01-01"
```

Comment: I don´t know if I´m mingy, but I avoid to load packages for little things.

Comment: @xm1, that's perfectly reasonable, but it also means you miss out on some little things, like default origin for Dates. You could, of course, look *how* the `zoo` package does it and copy it.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I´ve done my `as.date=function(x) as.Date(x,origin='1970-01-01')`

Answer (score 4):

There is an elegant and simple solution, like zoo, but allows for some tweaking if you need it:

`require(anytime)`

The base is simply:

`anytime(0)`
which returns for me in eastern standard time:`[1] "1969-12-31 19:00:00 EST"`

If you want to be able to force it to the UTC center of the temporal universe

`anytime(0, asUTC=TRUE)`

which returns

`[1] "1970-01-01 UTC"`

And if you want to tell R that you your data is from a given time zone :

`Sys.setenv(TZ= 'desiredTimeZone')` with `anytime:::getTZ()` as your desired time zone if that is the one, in which, your dates were gathered.

Any of the answers will work, this one just gives you control over the integer (or string) of numerals as well as the time zone...so it is pretty universally useful if you are working with data gathered remotely.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. There is no way the `origin` date can be changed and remain applicable forever in a session.

If you look at parameters for `as.Date` (i.e.  function then `origin` does not has a default value when `x` is in `numeric`.

```
## S3 method for class 'numeric'
as.Date(x, origin, ...)
```

Perhaps, it would have been a good extension to `as.Date` function to provide `default` value for `origin`.

OP has done write thing to create a wrapper function to remove dependency on `origin`. Perhaps the function can be improved slightly like:

Modified function based on suggestions from suggestions from @sm1 and @Gregor.

```
## if date.origin is not defined then origin will be taken as "1970-01-01
options(date.origin = "1970-01-01")
as.date <- function(x, origin = getOption("date.origin")){
  origin <- ifelse(is.null(origin), "1970-01-01", origin)
  as.Date(x, origin)
}

## Results: (When date.origin is not set)
## > as.date(0)
## [1] "1970-01-01"
## > as.date(2)
## [1] "1970-01-03"
## Results: (When date.origin is set)
## > options(date.origin = "1970-01-05")
## > as.date(2)
## [1] "1970-01-07"
```

Comment: won´t it be easier just `as.date <- function(x, origin = ORIGIN)`?

Comment: @xm1  That's good point. But we have consider a case when `ORIGIN` is not defined. Function should not crash or return errors in that case.

Comment: Probably would be better to set/get an option than use something in the global environment.

Comment: @Gregor good suggestion. I was about to work on handling cases when `ORIGIN` is not defined but seems `option` is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

The [`lubridate`](http://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) package has been specically made the work with dates easier :

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(0)
#[1] "1970-01-01"
```