# Addressing Supply Origin Error with [Is Na]

Tags: r

My code worked last month, so who knows what happened this, but the guy who wrote it is gone, so there that.

I've got a decent sized data frame, and trying to replace all the NA's with 0.
I'm using this:

```
sprink_df[is.na(sprink_df)] <-0
```

I keep getting the `as.POSIXct.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied` error, which I don't fully understand but I've figured out from browsing other answers is that it's related to how it deals with dates. However I'm a little unsure how to fix it.

I have one date column in this data frame, that shouldn't have NAs in it anyway, whose most recent modification before this line is

```
date <- as.Date(format(neutdf$CreatedTime)
```

The format is POSIXct and is %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS

I've tried other ways to replace all my NAs only to get numerous errs (based on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535505/replacing-all-missing-values-in-r-data-table-with-a-value), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe))

It looks like [someone had success by manually setting the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224405/imputing-a-rda-causes-origin-must-be-supplied-error), but when I tried it didn't help. Of course, I could be doing it wrong. My R experience is just playing around with others' code. *shrug*

I used `as.POSIXct(sprink_df$CreatedTime,tz="",origin="1970-01-01")` based on [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) and also tried

```
as.date <- function(sprink_df, origin = getOption("date.origin"))
  {origin <- ifelse(is.null(origin), "1970-01-01", origin)
  as.Date(sprink_df$CreatedTime, origin)}
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241567/r-set-default-origin-for-as-date) using the second option.

While I'm not against installing new packages, I'd rather work within what I have for this script - dplyr, rlang, digest, dint.

DATA EXAMPLE

I have 66 variables, of which run the gambmit from chr, num, logi, but the dput() of the column in question is `1548537133.685,1548537156.167, 1548537188.106, 1548537214.205`.

Which is a little different from the str() output for reasons I don't understand. `POSIXct[1:61608], format: "2019-01-23 15:20:13" "2019-01-24 19:29:12"`

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `sprink_df` using `dput(head(sprink_df))`? Or at a minimum, a sample of what the raw numeric date values look like?

Comment: Yeah, I'll post a sample from the column. There's 66 total, btw, of various formats.